# Map function in pointer vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

My task is to calculate a function in a vector:

```
 map<string, Operacija*> operacije;
```

This is line where i need to calculate:

```
  operacije["triangle"] = new Calculation1(4.2, 7);
```

This is my class:

```
class Operacija {
 public:
     int a;
     int b;
     Operacija(){}
     Operacija(int _a, int _b)
     {
         this->a = a;
         this->b = b;
     }    
 };
```

Should I put operation triangle into vector then calculate or should I make somehow function in class to calculate it. Operation Calculate should return `(a*b)/2`.

Comment: Typically one would use a `std::map<std::string, std::function<float(float, float)>` and store callables in it.

Comment: Can u type code I dont understand like this

Comment: I cant change first 2 lines

Comment: how is the pointer Calculation1 related to Operacija????

Comment: Operacija is class, operacije is a name of vector, operacije["triangle"] need to calculate 2 numbers and store it.

Comment: Also, *Operation Calculate should return (a*b)/2* - What is this `Calculate`?

Comment: uff my mistake it's function

Comment: For `new Calculation1(4.2, 7)` to be a valid expression, `Calculation1` must be a class type. Are you sure it's not `operacije["triangle"] = calculation1(4.2, 7);`, and asking you to define a function `Operacija* calculation1(double, double);`?

Comment: I dont know how to store operation ["triangle"] to vector and now i need to calculate calculation1 and return that number to operation ["triangle"]

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear because the code shown is incomplete and uses undeclared types, and the desired result / question being asked are also unclear.